# Is LSF queue allowed to preempt itself?

Tags: high-performance, platform-lsf

I have an LSF queue, say it's queue A. I only want higher priority jobs in queue A to preempt lower priority jobs in queue A, but not jobs in any other queues. If I set queue A to be preemptable, could I set it to be preemptable only by itself (queue A)? Or if this is not allowed, what could achieve my goal?

Comment: Your question is perhaps on-topic, if you're using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF on a UNIX system of some sort; are you?

Answer (score 0):

LSF support 2 modes of preemption: [Queue based](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/preemptive_sched_lsf_about.html) and [license based](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/license_scheduler/ls_preemption.html).  In your case, since the queue priority of your two jobs is the same (both are in the same queue) preemption won't be triggered.

If your two jobs are part of different license scheduler projects, and the running job is borrowing a license from the project of the pending job, then preemption can happen.  But from your description I'm guessing that this isn't the case.

Unfortunately preemption based on (for example) job priority or fairshare weight is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it looks like LSF only supports preemption based on queue priority, instead of job priority. I'd have to use 2 queues with different priorities maybe.